# Ansible + Cisco idempotence

Tags: ansible, cisco, idempotent

So I'm doing some testing with Ansible to manage Cisco devices (specifically a 3750 in this case).
I'm able to add my VLAN's and Loopbacks with no issue.

Just trying to get Ansible to stop registering a change in the task when the Loopback or VLAN exists.

Right now my play looks like this:

```
    - name: Set the IP for Loop 0
  ios_config:
    provider: "{{ connection }}"
    lines:
      - description AnsibleLoop0
      - ip address 8.8.8.8 255.255.255.0
    before:
      - interface Loopback0
    match: exact
```

Anytime this task is run, Ansible registers it like a change:

`changed: [switch] => {"changed": true, "updates": ["interface Loopback0", "description AnsibleLoop0", "ip address 8.8.8.8 255.255.255.0"], "warnings": []}`

I've tried different `match` types (`line, exact`) to no avail.
Maybe I'm getting something wrong here.

I thought that if I had the play insert the lines exactly like how they would show up in a `show run` it wouldnt register it as a change?

Any help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could be experiencing this issue:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/24345

Are you saving the configuration changes each time to the Cisco device using `save: "yes”` in your playbook? I had the same problem and I was saving the config each time the playbook ran. Setting that to `no` just to test, after the first run reports `changed=True` sequential runs would report back `changed=False` by Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread has been closed a long ago but just had the same problem and found what was causing it for me.

I am configuring L3 interfaces using a json file as a source, on which I did not realize I was using the value for interface name on uppercase like this: Loopback123

This is the result when using that:

changed: [NX-SPINE-2] => (item={'interface': 'Loopback123', 'ip': '123.1.2.8/32', 'description': 'Loopback interface for Ansible Testing'})
changed: [NX-SPINE-1] => (item={'interface': 'Loopback123', 'ip': '123.1.2.7/32', 'description': 'Loopback interface for Ansible Testing'})
changed: [NX-LEAF-3] => (item={'interface': 'Loopback123', 'ip': '123.1.2.5/32', 'description': 'Loopback interface for Ansible Testing'})
changed: [NX-LEAF-2] => (item={'interface': 'Loopback123', 'ip': '123.1.2.4/32', 'description': 'Loopback interface for Ansible Testing'})
changed: [NX-LEAF-4] => (item={'interface': 'Loopback123', 'ip': '123.1.2.6/32', 'description': 'Loopback interface for Ansible Testing'})

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
NX-LEAF-1                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
NX-LEAF-2                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
NX-LEAF-3                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
NX-LEAF-4                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
NX-SPINE-1                 : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
NX-SPINE-2                 : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

This is due to interface name actually being different to how the device treats and displays the name back when showing the configuration.

interface loopback0
description Management - BGP peering

Once I corrected the interface name to lower case on the source file, this solved the idempotency check for me.

ok: [NX-LEAF-4] => (item={'interface': 'loopback123', 'ip': '123.1.2.6/32', 'description': 'Loopback interface for Ansible Testing'})
ok: [NX-LEAF-3] => (item={'interface': 'loopback123', 'ip': '123.1.2.5/32', 'description': 'Loopback interface for Ansible Testing'})

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
NX-LEAF-1                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
NX-LEAF-2                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
NX-LEAF-3                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
NX-LEAF-4                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
NX-SPINE-1                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
NX-SPINE-2                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Hope it helps.

Cheers!