# How create with "match" and "replace" idempotent Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, cisco

I am trying to create idempotent playbooks for our Cisco switches, I read a lot of documentation but there must be something I am missing here...

I have a playbook, where I call my role where I need to setup my switchports:

**/etc/ansible/playbook.yml**

```
 ...   
   roles:
 ...  
   - role: set_acc_switchports
       access_ports: g1/0/1 - 2
```

**/etc/ansible/roles/set_acc_switchports/tasks/main.yml:**

```
- name: Set switchports to default
  ios_config:
    lines:
      - switchport access vlan 169
      - switchport mode access
      - switchport port-security
     parents: interface range {{ access_ports }}
     match: strict
     replace: line
```

Here's the thing: It sets the ports, but when I run the playbook again, althought there is exactly the same config already (and ONLY that config), the output is always that this role has changed something, instead of just ok:

```
...
TASK [set_acc_switchports : Set switchports to default] *****************************************************************************
changed: [Switch]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************
Switch: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I tried tweaking the match and replace params but no luck. I would really appreciate some help, thank you.

Comment: there was an issue https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/24563 but it is closed. Maybe an ansible update would help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157181/ansible-cisco-idempotence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you use abbreviated commands/names.

Take a look at the [Ansible Network FAQ](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/faq.html#why-do-the-config-modules-always-return-changed-true-with-abbreviated-commands).

Comment: Thank you! It didn't occur to me that also the "g1/0/1-2" could cause the problem. Replaced with full interface names and works like a charm.